# 'DataTemplate' type does not have a public TypeConverter class

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have created the following `DataTemplate` for a `GridViewColumn`.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!--'DataTemplate' type does not have a public TypeConverter class.-->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myCellTemplate">        
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" ToolTip="{Binding}" Background="Red" />
      </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I use the `DataTemplate` here:

```
    <ListView 
      ItemsSource="{Binding AllOrders}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"
                    CellTemplate="myCellTemplate" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I am receiving the following error:

> 'DataTemplate' type does not have a public TypeConverter class.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `myCellTemplate` with `{StaticResource myCellTemplate}` as follows:

```
 <GridViewColumn 
      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"
      CellTemplate="{StaticResource myCellTemplate}" />
```